# How to execute a perforce command like 'diff' within a P4api.net?

Tags: perforce, p4api.net

I am working with a p4api.net application and I need to make use of perforce 'diff' command in it. I couldn't find a right approach to execute this command. I need a way to execute the command inside the application and get its result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you've tried so far, or what the specific problem is, the best we can do is point you to the [P4API.NET documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/Index.html) for the [diff](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/M_Perforce_P4_Repository_GetDepotFileDiffs.htm) method.

Comment: I was trying to use P4Command class and then trying to execute diff command in it. Since I was using Repository class for connection, I used Repository type parameter along with other parameters in the P4Command constructor. But, while execution, a break happens showing me with a message to use P4Server parameter.